# Pull special character using Sqoop

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I am stuck at one point with sqoop.
In my source I have one column which have one special character. But when I am pulling the data with sqoop, the special character is changed to something else.

In my source oracle table i have :-

```
jan 2005 �DSX�
```

but when it is sqooping data to hive table, it changed the special character to something else

```
jan 2005 �DSXÙ
```

Please suggest some solution so that I get exact same special character as it is in source (Oracle) table.

```
sqoop import \ 
--connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@source connection details" \ 
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager \
--username abc \
--password xyz \
--fields-terminated-by '\001' \
--null-string '' \
--null-non-string '' \ 
--query "select column_name from wxy.ztable where \$CONDITIONS " \ 
--target-dir "db/dump/dir" \ 
--split-by "col1" \
-m 1
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add your sqoop import command? Also please post the value of your NLS_LANG environment variable. I think NLS_LANG should match sqoop's default character set.

Comment: sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@source connection details" \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager --username abc --password xyz --fields-terminated-by '\001' --null-string '' --null-non-string '' \
--query "select column_name from wxy.ztable where \$CONDITIONS " \
--target-dir "db/dump/dir" \
--split-by "col1" -m 1

Answer (score 0):

if you are seeing `jan 2005 �DSX�` this in your oracle table, probably your encoding for oracle table is also not set correctly. I don't have much experience with oracle so won't be able to tell you how to check, however you can check with your oracle DBA.

One thing I can tell you is, Hadoop using `UTF-8` encoding, so you first need to convert your oracle to `UTF-8` and then import the data.